# Runtime error 9, subscript out of range

Tags: vba, excel

I've been trying to create a function to run the `FindNext` function ***n*** times in VBA so that I can find the ***n<sup>th</sup>*** occurrence of a number within a range.

Whenever I try to call this function I get the error:

> Runtime error 9: Subscript out of range

The code that I have tried is listed below:

```
Function FindZero(FindNum As Integer, InputRange As Range, N As Integer)
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim cell As Range

    For Each cell In InputRange.Cells
        For i = 0 To i < N
            cell = InputRange.FindNext(FindNum)
            MsgBox "The active cell address = " & cell.Address
        Next i
    Next cell
End Function
```

I would appreciate your help

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  On which line do you get the error?

Comment: You're using a findnext without a find. Also Set to a find or findnext.

Comment: @Jeeped - did not notice the Findnext without find

Comment: @wonderman Do you need to return the cell address or a range object?

Comment: @wonderwoman - I answered with a function that will return the cell address (or could be modified to return a range object),

Answer (score 0):

The content of the For-loop should be like this:

```
Set cell = InputRange.Find.FindNext(FindNum)
If Not cell is Nothing Then MsgBox "The active cell address = " & cell.Address
```

There are 3 errors in the code:

1. `cell` is a Range object. Thus, the word `Set` is used;
2. If there is no next value, make a check for not nothing, before showing the `MsgBox`;
3. The `FindNext` should be used with `Find` before (as noted in the comments from @Jeeped);

Answer (score 0):

Here is a variation on your function that should work for you:

```
Public Function findNth(toFind As Variant, searchRange As Range, findOccurence As Long) As String
'returns the [findOccurence] occurence of [toFind] (number or text) within [searchRange]

    Dim n As Long, found As Range, firstMatch As Range
    Set found = searchRange.Cells.Find(toFind)
    If found Is Nothing Then
        'Debug.Print toFind & " not found"
        findNth = "" 'not found
        Exit Function
    End If
    Set firstMatch = found

    Do
        n = n + 1
        Debug.Print "Match#" & n & "/" & findOccurence & ": " & found.Address
        Set found = searchRange.FindNext(found)
        If found Is Nothing Or found = firstMatch Then
            'Debug.Print "(Only " & n & "/" & toFind & " occurrences were found)"
            findNth = "" 'not found
            Exit Function
        End If

    Loop While n <= findOccurence
    findNth = found.Address
End Function
```

---

### Example Usage:

This example returns the cell address of the **7**<sup>th</sup> match of the value `22`, within cells `A2:E13` on worksheet `myWkSheet`.

```
Sub testFind()
    Dim cellAddy As String
    cellAddy = findNth(22, Sheets("myWkSheet").Range("A2:E13"), 7)

    If cellAddy = "" Then
        MsgBox "Match not found"
    Else
        MsgBox "Found in cell: " & cellAddy
    End If
End Sub
```

---

### More Information:

- MSDN : [**Range.`Find` Method**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-find-method-excel) (Excel)
- MSDN : [**Range.`FindNext` Method**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-findnext-method-excel) (Excel)